In Laravel Jetstream I can't upload a picture >2MB
I have a issue without answer. I created a new Laravel project with Jetstream and livewire stack. I dont make any modification,its fresh I just want to upload a photo profile and it work with any file less than 2mb, but not beyond it.
My php.ini is well configured with post_max_size, upload_max_filesize at 100M and 80M. My UpdateUserProfileInformation.php in app/Actions/Fortify is well configured with "'photo' => ['nullable', 'mimes:jpg,jpeg,png', 'max:10240']," It seems that a photo>2MB is directly reject when I load it with a red message

The photo failed to upload

without even be sending. I think the problem come from the input field in the update-information-form.blade.php line 41 "<x-secondary-button class="mt-2 me-2" type="button" x-on:click.prevent="$refs.photo.click()">", maybe they are something wrong with the function "$refs.photo.click()". Do you have a solution for it? I will help me and other Laravel Jetstream user.
I try to upload a profile picture in laravel jetstream but it work only with file sized less than 2MB

Your webserver also has a say in it; client_max_body_size for nginx and LimitRequestBody in Apache. Apache's default is 2MB, I think.

Thanks you, the reason was i dont configured my php.

I find the solution for my problem, I dont configured my PHP install where they are a  php.ini on the install folder, so you have to configure the php on your install and on the apache server.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
